# Birt Date format

Tags: eclipse, birt

I have an input parameter that is in yyyy - mm format in Birt Eclipse and I need to find the last day of the selected input parameter value and convert into mm/dd/yyyy format. For example if user selects - 2022 - 02 then I need to find the last day - 02/28/2022 and pass it to an another filter.

I am trying with the below Java expression but not sure where the issue is

Can someone please help. I have been stuck at this issue for weeks.

```
var mydt1 =params["Period To"].value
importPackage(Packages.java.util);
importPackage(Packages.java.text);
df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy - MM");
myDate = df.parse(mydt1);
cal = new Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(myDate);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.getActualMaximum(cal.DAY_OF_MONTH));
lastDate = cal.getTime();
datefm = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
ddd = datefm.format(lastDate);
return ddd;
```

Comment: You don't tell us what kind of report you want to create. If you are working with an Oracle DB for example, you could use Oracle's SQL function LAST_DAY function, which exists in other SQL databases, too.

Comment: Thank You for the response. We are using the TRIRIGA application and not the DB to fetch the data. Hence can't use the Oracle LAST DAY Function.

Comment: Isn't this a Javascript (or Java, since we access it from BIRT Javascript) question then? Sorry, can't assist you here. I hate how complicated data handling in Java is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this option, if you have a `DateTime` parameter:

```
var date = Formatter.format(BirtDateTime.addDay(BirtDateTime.addMonth(BirtDateTime.firstDayOfMonth(params["Period To"].value),1)-1),"MM/dd/yyyy")
```

First, we get the first day of this month, then add 1 month, then decrement by 1 day to get the last day of the month.